# Vertical slider like Uber.com that shares scroll bar with entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have an effect similar to that of Uber.com. When scrolling the background stops and the text scrolls, and the images snap into the phone image with a sort of parallax feel when scrolling. I am looking for advice on how to make something similar, or if you know of any plugin that does that, that would also be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a "do my work for me" type of question. What have you tried so far? Show us some code or that you have done some research.

Comment: I am not looking for code per say, but more of an approach. I was thinking about using a vertical carousel/slider but that isn't controlled by the "master" scroll bar for the entire page.

Comment: look at this plugin and you should get a pretty clear idea https://mango.github.io/slideout/

Comment: I am not looking for the side menu, but the middle of the page where it starts off with "Tap the app, get a ride"

Comment: Have you got the solution for this? would be great if you share the fiddle link

Comment: I don't have a fiddle link, but I have done my best attempt here: http://kuririi.com/